# warning: URGENT: building for watchOS simulator but linking object file built for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchos-2, j2objc, watchos-simulator

While integrating my java library converted by j2objc I'm receiving this message.

> ld: warning: URGENT: building for watchOS simulator, but linking in
>   object file
>   (/Users/admin/Documents/j2objc/dist/lib/libjre_emul.a(IOSArray.o))
>   built for iOS. Note: This will be an error in the future.

I do not understand will my code work on real watchOS device? Or this is just a i386 build which works only in the simulator? What I have to do in this case?

Comment: your library is converted to iOS not WatchOS , they are not always compatible

Comment: @ogres, is it possible to detect will this library crash in the real watchOS device without it? As I understood now it works on simulator due to i386 processor. I so that this library build for armv7k and watch7k  . But I do not understand this warning and behaviour. How to build this library for watchOS? Which `destination` flag i have to use for `xcodebuild` tool?

Comment: you have to test it yourself, cant say for sure